# How to configure oracle in reporting services for SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I'm working with SQL server 2016 web edition, and I'm trying to configure the reporting services to work with oracle. I have already installed the 2 editions of oracle (32 and 64 bits) and odp.net. Additionally, I already changed the file in tsnames.ora with the information of the service instance.

Everything works well except when I try to run the report in the preview, where I'm getting the next error:

> An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ORACLE' that is
>   either not registered for this report server or is not supported in
>   this edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound)
>   ---------------------------- An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

Comment: Did you run the installs on your dev machine?

Comment: yes, everything was installed on dev machine and on the server too